# Можно ли создать свою версию игры используя авторские ресурсы?

Tags: разработка-игр, лицензирование, ресурсы

Очень захотелось написать свою копию игры (Mappy, вышла в 1983 - под платформу Nintendo). Соответственно все ресурсы хочу взять оттуда (текстуры, музыку).

Является ли это нарушением авторского права? (насколько я понимаю, по истечении 28 лет - нет)

Comment: Один из вариантов (не знаю, насколько он легален с точки зрения законодательства) использовать оригинальные ресурсы в вашей игре при наличии лицензионной копии. Так поступают различные эмуляторы, и некоторые homebrew игрушки (например https://github.com/AMDmi3/openstrike).

Comment: Можно было бы связаться с ними и спросить. Может они не против.

Comment: @Qwertiy, очень дельный совет, я почему-то об этом не подумал. Спасибо, напишу им

Answer (score 2):

Нашел ответ - https://www.nintendo.com/corp/legal.jsp#expired

Права на игру истекут в течение 75 лет со дня первого релиза

Comment: Там же японский разработчик. Почему отсылка к американским законам?

Comment: @Qwertiy, довольно сложно сказать (я в юриспруденции не силен). Возможно фирма зарегистирована в Штатах, вот и используют американское законодательство (мое предположение)

Comment: @Qwertiy, кажется я немного ступил, вы имели ввиду что разработчик Namco (японская компания)? тогда да, получается что я не там ответ искал

Comment: Ты вроде не на сайт разработчика игры ссылаешься? Можно как-то подробнее?

Comment: Да, я имел в виду Namco.

Answer (score 1):

*Я не юрист*

Обычно все ресурсы принадлежат кому-то (создателю, компании разработчику, компании издателю, третьим лицам). В ходе разработки, издания, перепродажи прав, они могут не раз сменить владельцев.

Первая большая проблема, найти в чьем-же они ведении сейчас. А точнее - кто обладает на них правами. Например, музыкант мог написать музыку и передать издательству права на ее однократное использование, сохранив за собой права на ее переиздание.

Вторая проблема - получение разрешения. За редкими исключениями, ни один правообладатель не будет лишать себя ценных владений, которые "лежат и есть не просят". Это касается в первую очередь торговых марок, названий, художественных образов. Подумайте, в чем ценность правообладателю передавать права?

Первое решение, нереальное, - найти, договориться, компенсировать.

Второе решение, реалистичное - придумать свою игру "по мотивам", сделать ресурсы самому.

Третье решение, простое - придумать свою игру "по мотивам" и использовать общедоступные ресурсы (по типу CC0).

P.S. Речь выше о ресурсах. Игровые механики и идеи, обычно (за исключением Тетриса, например), не подлежат патентованию. Поэтому в игрострое так много клонов и разработок существующих идей.

P.P.S. Имейте ввиду, что подать в суд может любая компания, почувствовшая, что её ущемили, и соотношение сил будет далеко не в вашу пользу. Даже если вы 100 раз правы, для разрабатываемой игры это, скорее всего, будет катастрофично.